# SendGrid Email SDK - Java

Tags: java, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3, sendgrid-templates

I am using SendGrid SDK for sending the email. But below I am facing the issue of sending the dynamic values.

In the Sendgrid Java 4.0.1 version, I can use the dynamic template but can't send the dynamic value like `{{name}}`.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sendgrid</groupId>
        <artifactId>sendgrid-java</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

I tried the Sendgrid Java 4.7.1 version, but I can't import the package `com.sendgrid.helpers`. It's throwing an error, ****cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class Mail
[ERROR]   location: package com.sendgrid****

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sendgrid</groupId>
        <artifactId>sendgrid-java</artifactId>
        <version>4.7.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

What is the correct Sendgrid SDK version to implement the dynamic template and dynamic values in Java?

Answer (score 0):

you can use sendgrid version : **4.6.4**

```
implementation group: 'com.sendgrid', name: 'sendgrid-java', version: '4.6.4'
```

While trying dynamic values , set your personalisations by addDynamicTemplateData.